# Pandas aggregate modifies indexes

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I'm using this function to calculate in my dataframe, for each id and for each hour, mean, median and variance of the 'value' column:

```
df = df.groupby(['PatientID', 
pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='60T')])['Value'].agg(['mean', 'median', 
'var'])
```

But in the newly modified dataframe I correctly get the mean, median and variance, but date and id are not evaluated and greyed as in this screen:
[image]

I would like to keep date and ID. How do i fix this? Thank you

Comment: Would adding `.reset_index()` help?

Comment: I'm so dumb, I was using .set_index() instead of .reset_index(). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Simply add .reset_index() to the code to avoid the problem